# Oracle XE 10g Ubuntu removed from oracle web site?

Tags: ubuntu, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I can't find Oracle XE 10g anymore on Oracle web site. I'm using 32 bit GNU/Linux Ubuntu 12.04.

There's only 11g xe version on they'r website, that I can't install under my operating system.

Does somebody have this distribution?

Could you please share link with me, where from I can download this distribution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link on oracle.com is not available/linked/visible officially anymore, but still out there in the wild:

```
http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle10g/xe/10201/oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb
```

If you just click the link, you'll get an error message, so you have to

1. Login in to oracle.com, for example at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/downloads/index.html
2. Accept the license agreement (cookies get set) and click on download for any 11g XE (don't need to download, just cancel after it started)
3. copy and paste the URL `http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle10g/xe/10201/oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb` into your browser address bar and the download starts
4. install with `sudo dpkg -i oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb` etc.

**This solution worked as of 2012-07-24, no guarantees the .deb file will be available in the future, this is Oracle's decision.**

Comment: Any suggestion for Oracle XE 10g for Ubuntu 64bit.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but when _I_ google "oracle-xe_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb Ubuntu 64bit" the first few links all show reasonable HowTos...

Answer (score 22):

Debian packages for Oracle XE 10g are still available at :

```
https://oss.oracle.com/debian/dists/unstable/non-free/binary-i386/
```

Comment: I hope this won't be dead faster than others

Answer (score 3):

New url to download Oracle XE 10g is from:

http://www.4shared.com/get/AnYhQhAD/oracle-xe_10201-10_i386.html

Comment: this 4shared link is dead. any other mirror ?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the rpm packages for 10g, you can still find them at http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/pub/fedora/6/i386/.

I was able to download them on 2014-08-22.

Answer (score 0):

for Oracle XE 11g on Ubuntu 64-bit, check this out

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2303639

also here you can find Virtual Machines provided by Oracle, with a package to serve your needs (weather Database development or Java EE development)

Oracle Virtual Machine :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

Pre-Built VM's :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

you can find the Oracle Database in the 'Database App Development VM'